# Place icon in corner of centered image

Tags: css

I have an image centered in the viewport using `flex`:

```html
<!-- This div simulates the viewport: -->
<div style="resize: both; overflow: auto; width: 192px; height: 108px;">
  <div style="background-color: #AAA; height: 100%; width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
    <img style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;" src="https://placekitten.com/800/600">
  </div>
</div>
```

The outermost div represents the viewport, you can resize it.

Now I would like to show an icon in the top right corner **of the image** (not of the gray area).

Can I do that with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the property of `flex`, which the sibling element will be relatively position to the sibling. After that, with a bit of creativity, you can create a 0px relative `div` to be used as an anchor for your absolute positioned icon, example here:

```html
<!-- This div simulates the viewport: -->
<div style="resize: both; overflow: auto; width: 192px; height: 108px;">
  <div style="background-color: #AAA; height: 100%; width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
    <img style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;" src="https://placekitten.com/800/600">
    <div style="position: relative; top: 0; align-self: flex-start">
      <div style="position: absolute; right: 0"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I drag the "viewport" to be more narrow than tall, the icon isn't in the corner of the image anymore: https://i.imgur.com/DztyJLP.png

Comment: Oops @AndreKR you are right, let me think again on how to hack it with pure CSS...